# C# Combobo back color change on if or starement

Tags: c#

I have a number of combo boxes that do a number of things related to data. I'm struggling however with the if else and or.

I have a combo which has four items in the list YES, NO, Yes Catostrophic and Yes Controlled these relate to bleeds medically just for info.

Currently I have:

```
if (cbcathem.text == "yes")
       lbcathem.backcolor = color.pink
```

Which changes the color nicely.

I have tried:

```
if (cbcathem.text == "yes|yes controlled")
       lbcathem.backcolor = color.pink
```

But this does not work so, in essence, I want the label to go pink when any one of three is selected but the 4th remains untouched.

Comment: Hi, Dave. Please supply a full (and concise) code sample for what is and what isn't working for you, so that people can help you. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Dave, do not forget to select on of the answer as a solution from the community :)

Answer (score 4):

`if (cbcathem.text == "yes|yes controlled")`

should be changed to

```
if (cbcathem.text == "yes" || cbcathem.text == "yes controlled")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (cbcathem.text == "yes" || cbcathem.text == "yes controlled") lbcathem.backcolor = color.pink
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static variable

```
static int  i = 1;
```

And each time you click you do

```
i+=1;
```

so when arrive at i =4 you do whatever you want